# wsman requests in apache server

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsman

I had configured mod_wsman module in apache server.  got xml error response when entering ip address in browser. I have also configured mod_wsgi module for web.py python web framework for rendering web pages. So I had given valid urls in browser, it didn't displayed. 
Is any body working on mod_wsman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache and WSMAN services are run in a separate process state. Apache is working in 80 ports, while WSMAN service work in other ports, such as port 8889.

Module to write the most important is to write the the wsman a hook function wsman_handler (request_rec * r), its incoming parameter is a pointer point to the Apache message, the beginning of the function is to determine the type of request, if not is wsman request, the module returns DECLINED The code shown below,

if( strcmp(r->handler, "wsman-handler")) if (strcmp (r-> handler, "wsman-handler")) 
         return DECLINED; return DECLINED